# in org-mode, is there a function to export (current) subtree to HTML?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, is there a function to export (current) subtree to HTML? How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With Org 8:

```
M-x org-export-dispatch
C-s (change the export scope to subtree)
h (HTML menu)
h (export to HTML file)
```

Comment: Yes, just define a keyboard macro with these commands (see [KeyboardMacros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/KeyboardMacros)). Note that in recent versions of org mode you can also export the last subtree you were at no matter where you are by using "C-u C-c C-e" (and of course you can define a macro to do so).

Comment: You can assign the function call `(org-html-export-to-html nil t)` to whichever function. Create an explicit command, or wrap the above in a `(lambda ...)` expression (see anonymous functions).

Answer (score 29):

You can also use `org-narrow-to-subtree` to reduce the buffer and run the normal export.

Comment: Much better than my kludge.

Comment: It is bounded to the keystroke `C-x n s`, and to return to the widen view `C-x n w`. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: In that case the numbering stays global, whereas changing the scope does enumerate from start and uses the headline as title. Using both sets a clear picture.

Answer (score 8):

When transient-mark-mode is turned on, only the active region will export.

The information for ODT export found [here,](http://orgmode.org/manual/ODT-export-commands.html) also works with HTML.

Comment: Excellent choice when exporting multiple headlines

Answer (score 1):

The function is `org-html-export-to-html` which can be called with arguments `nil t` to export the current subtree.

```
(defun subtree-html () 
  (interactive) 
  (org-html-export-to-html nil t))
```

You can also create macro (which may then be executed by a function).

Steps:

1. Start recording a keyboard macro: `C-x (` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#Basic-Keyboard-Macro
2. Follow the steps of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20630177/1137803 (`M-x org-export-dispatch C-s h h`)
3. Stop recording the macro: `C-x e`
4. Saving with `kmacro-name-last-macro` (not `name-last-kbd-macro`)
5. Inserting to file with `M-x insert-kbd-macro`
6. Replace `setq last-kbd-macro` with `execute-kbd-macro`
7. Now you can make this a (potentially interactive) function (or put it into a lambda and bind to a key). E.g. `(defun subtree-html () (interactive) (execute-kbd-macro _____))` where `_____` is the output of `insert-kbd-macro`.

If there is a less convoluted way to do this that doesn't impact visibility/narrowing (or can easily restore it), I'm curious to hear it.